# erlang mysql multiple row result to xml

Tags: mysql, xml, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I have multiple row result of mysql select in erlang :

```
{_,_, Result} = ejabberd_odbc:sql_query(Server,
                            [<<"select group, GROUP_CONCAT(members.username separator ', ') AS member from members WHERE id='">>,Id,<<"'">>]),
```

Result = [{"group","username1,username2, username3 ......."}....       {"group","username1,username2, username3 ......."}]

want to convert results to xml element :

```
xml = <group "xxxxxx">
          <members>
                <member>
                   <username>xxxxxx</username>
                </member>
                <member>
                   <username>xxxxxx</username>
                </member>
                <member>
                    .........
                </member>
           </members>
       </group>
       ........
       <group "xxxxxx">
          <members>
                <member>
                   <username>xxxxxx</username>
                </member>
                <member>
                   <username>xxxxxx</username>
                </member>
                <member>
                    .........
                </member>
           </members>
       </group>
```

any easy way to place it into xmpp iq sub element in a loop :

```
SubEl = [#xmlel{name = <<"members">>,
         attrs = [{<<"xmlns">>, ?NS_CHAT}],
         children = [#xmlel{name=<<"member">>,
                      attrs = [{<<"username">>, Username1}],
                      children = []}]
                    [#xmlel{name=<<"member">>,
                      attrs = [{<<"username">>, Username2}],
                      children = []}]
                      .............
                    }],
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that might work for you:

```
create_xml() ->
  % Your result set
  Input =[{"group1","username1,username2, username3"},
          {"group2","username21,username22, username23"}],

  Result = lists:map(fun(Group) -> [group_header(element(1, Group)),
                          create_segment(Group), 
                          "</members> </group>"] 
           end, 
           Input)
lists:flatten(Result).

% Create each group segment by folding over each group 
create_segment(Group) ->
  Tokenized = string:tokens(element(2, Group), ","),
  lists:foldl(fun(UserName, Acc) ->
                [Acc, "<member> <username>", UserName, 
                 "</username>  </member>"]
              end,
              "",
              Tokenized).

group_header(GroupName) ->
  ["<group \"", GroupName, "\"", "<members>"].
```

Running the above, I get:
    t:create_xml().

```
"<group \"group1\" <members> <member> <username>username1</username>  </member><member> <username>username2</username>  </member><member> <username> username3</username>  </member></members> </group><group \"group2\"<members><member> <username>username21</username>  </member><member> <username>username22</username>  </member><member> <username> username23</username>  </member></members> </group>"
```